# Dompdf generates pdf and downloads to pc but displays error on brower ( Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using codeigniter and trying to get dompdf working, when I call the function, it just downloads the file to my DOWNLOAD folder in desktop but doesnt output it to the screen.

```
public function generateCreditAggreement(){
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

            $dompdf = new Dompdf();

            $dompdf->load_html('<h1>hello world</h1>');

            // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
            $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'Potrait');

            // Render the HTML as PDF
            $dompdf->render();

            // Output the generated PDF to Browser
            $dompdf->stream('document.pdf');


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create library file called
Pdf.php
put this code

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

class Pdf extends DOMPDF
{

protected function ci()
{
    return get_instance();
}


public function load_view($view, $data = array())
{
    $html = $this->ci()->load->view($view, $data, TRUE);

    $this->load_html($html);
}
} ?>
```

And use to load the library in your controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("pdf");
}
```

And then

```
public function index()
{


        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

            $html ='
            <html>
            <head>


            </head>

            <body style="font-family:Helvetica;">

                    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%;"  style="border: 1px solid#d8d8d8; line-height:22px; padding:20px; font-size:13px; font-family:Helvetica;">
                    <tr >
                            <td  width="60%;" valign="top">
                               gxcbx</td> 

                        </tr >
                        </td>
                    </table>

            </body>
            </html>';


  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'Potrait');
  $dompdf->render();

  $dompdf->stream("hello.pdf"); 
  }
```

Try this way.

Comment: Try above formation . We have another way to implement. Step 1: Move Dompdf folder files to codeigniter Libraries from third party. Step 2: Replace require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'; by require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'); in Pdf.php that is above library file

Comment: Hey gopal if I have a very huge html page which needs to be outputing maybe 6 pages of pdf but then it gives me this error  

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Frame not found in cellmap' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\faceloan\faceloan\application\third_party\dompdf\include\cellmap.cls.php on line 244

How can I fix this ??

Comment: That means you may not have fully Dompdf package. Check it. But for me working fine even have morethan 12pages.

Comment: So how can I get a fully dompdf package? the version 0.6.0 was the one I downloaded

Comment: That error actually means there was a problem rendering your HTML. If you can do so, update to 0.7.0 which includes some fixes for table cell problems.

Comment: @BrianS I cant update it since 0.7.0 doesnt support in PHP codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

The [Dompdf stream method](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#stream) triggers a file download by default. If you want the PDF to appear in the browser window call the method like this:

```
$dompdf->stream('document.pdf', array('Attachment'=>0));
```